# importing haskell module says "not in scope"

Tags: class, haskell, instance

I created a Tree structure in a file called Tree2.hs

```
module Tree2
(
 Tree
) where

data Tree a = EmptyTree | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show)
```

then I imported it and tried to use it as an instance of a class

```
import qualified Tree2

class YesNo a where
  yesno :: a -> Bool

instance YesNo (Tree2.Tree a) where
  yesno EmptyTree = False
  yesno _ = True
```

But I'm getting this Error when loading it in ghci:

```
Not in scope: data constructor ‘EmptyTree’
Failed, modules loaded: Tree2.
```

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First,

```
module Tree2
(
 Tree
) where
```

only exports the `Tree` data type, not its constructors; you should use

```
module Tree2
(
  Tree(..)
) where
```

instead.

Second, as you're doing a qualified import, you need to use `Tree2.EmptyTree` instead of just `EmptyTree`.